# Data Manager issue in Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTransformName' of null

I'm having an issue with certain objects in the Data Manager in Einstein Analytics. I can create a sfdcDigest node but when I try to augment it, the object shows no available fields. If I try to just turn it straight into an sfdcRegister node, I get a spinning wheel and the below error in Chrome's developer window which shows some kind of Uncaught TypeError. Does anyone have any insight on what might be causing this?

```
edge.vendors~app.chunk.5cd6299e14fccd17a691.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTransformName' of null
at edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:1
at Array.find (<anonymous>)
at t.e.getSourceTransform (edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:1)
at t._getFields (edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:6)
at t.e.getFields (edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:1)
at edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:6
at t._runUpstreamUpdate (edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:6)
at t._runDownstreamUpdate (edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:6)
at t._updateGraphEdges (edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:6)
at t._onCreateNodeFromTransform(edge.dataManager.chunk.879df1231ebd957a631c.js:6)
```

Comment: Could you post the json of the dataflow?

Comment: The json is pretty large, there's a lot of nodes. I think it's a memory issue with the Salesforce instance because sometimes if I wait long enough I can get things to work. Additionally, sometimes when I create a new node, PREVIOUS nodes are overwritten.